# Configure visibility of block based on URL parameters

Tags: 8, blocks

Is it possible to display a block only on a URL without any parameters? E.g. on:

- my.site.org/search

but not on:

- my.site.org/search?q=term

When I configure a block ('/admin/structure/block/manage/myblock') and set visibility for pages at: '**/search**' (see the picture), then the block is displayed on the page '**/search?q=term**' as well.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [condition_query](https://www.drupal.org/project/condition_query) it will give you an extra box where you can put query parameters like `q=term`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosK. I hoped, that it is possible without an additional module. I need it in a project, where are allowed only modules, which are covered by the Drupal security advisory policy. So it looks like I have to find a workaround. E.g. the search results can be displayed on some other URL, like: search/results?q=term

Comment: well its either this or create your own implementation in a module or your theme. why would your implementation be more secure than a module already used by more than 186 sites?

Comment: Generally there is at the moment too much custom code in the project. So for unimportant functionality it is not recommended to add new code. But your solution can be quite usefull for other projects.